# Change korean font-style

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to change font-style for korean letters to 'dotum' (돋움) using css. Does anyone know how to do this? I downloaded dotum ttc file from cool text, moved it into my css folder, and wrote css as below, but still doesn't work.

```
body {
    font-family: "돋움", "Dotum", tahoma;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to declare the font first by adding the following to your css:

```
@font-face { 
     font-family: Dotum; 
     src: url('css/Dotum.ttc'); 
}
```

After that it's like you already did before:

```
body {
    font-family: "돋움", "Dotum", tahoma;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In that case remove the `css/` part from the `src: url('css/Dotum.ttc');` @KatieDongYoonOk

Comment: To clarify: if you look in the error and check out the link, you will see that it goes into a css folder twice, which usually isn't used like that. @KatieDongYoonOk

Comment: Thank you, taking css outside the url fixed it!

Comment: @KatieDongYoonOk no problem, please don't forget to mark this answer as the correct answer, this helps other people find the right answer much faster